# How to setup secure peer to peer communication between 2 wireless linux devices?

Tags: linux, security, ssl, networking, tls1.2

I have some wireless linux devices which need to securely exchange data. They do not need internet access. How can I set up a secure private network? I was able to successfully communicate via an adhoc network following:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ad-hoc_networking

Unfortunately wpa supplicant does not support WPA2 for adhoc networking.

How can 2 nodes securely communicate?

Could one become a WPA2 wireless access point they both connect to and exchange data via a TLS socket?

Perhaps one could become a hotspot? Or do I need to setup a private network using something like the ipsec framework strongswan?

Or maybe a TLS socket over an adhoc network is secure? WPA2 can be cracked in a few hours with open source software.

Answer (score -1):

How about SSH? Traffic is encrypted.

Comment: Yes, SSH would definitely achieve what I'm trying to do. Unfortunately ssh and dropbear are not allowed in the specific deployment so I need to find an alternative.